# Makefile not linking the .o files

Tags: c++, makefile

I have been provided the following Makefile to compile my project. It seems to be written in pretty old-fashioned style, and although I am reading the official GNU Make manual I am not able to fix it. The project itself seems to correctly compile all the .o files, as it creates all of them in my working directory: main.o model.o param.o

```
# //////////////// NOMBRE DEL PROYECTO /////////////////// 
#
P=project
#

EXE=$(P)
OBJS=main.o model.o param.o head.h

ADDLIBS=-D.
ADDINCFLAGS=-I.

SRCDIR=/root/projects/project

########## 


CXX=g++

CXXFLAGS=-O3 -fomit-frame-pointer -pipe -DNDEBUG -pedantic-errors -Wparentheses -Wreturn-type -Wcast-qual -Wall -Wpointer-arith -Wwrite-strings -Wconversion -I$(COININCDIR)
CXXLINKFLAGS=-Wl,--rpath -Wl,/installed/CoinAll/lib



CC=gcc

CFLAGS=-03 -fomit-frame-pointer -pipe -DNDEBUG -pedantic-errors -Wimplicit -Wparentheses -Wsequence-point -Wreturn-type -Wcast-qual -Wall


COININCDIR=/installed/CoinAll/include/coin

COINLIBDIR=/installed/CoinAll/lib


LIBS=-L$(COINLIBDIR) -lCbc -lCgl -lOsiClp -lOsi -lClp -lCoinUtils -lm \
`cat $(COINLIBDIR)/cgl_addlibs.txt` \
`cat $(COINLIBDIR)/clp_addlibs.txt` \
`cat $(COINLIBDIR)/coinutils_addlibs.txt` 

# LIBS=-L$(COINLIBDIR) -lClp -lCoinUtils \
# -lm `cat $(COINLIBDIR)/coinutils_addlibs.txt`

INCL=-I`$(COININCDIR)`$(ADDINCFLAGS)



all: $(EXE)

.SUFFIXES: .cpp .c .o .obj

$(EXE): $(OBJS)
    bla=;
    for file in $(OBJS); do bla="$$bla ` $$file`"; done; \
    $(CXX) $(CXXLINKFLAGS) $(CXXFLAGS) -o $@ $$bla $(ADDLIBS) $(LIBS)   


.cpp.o:
    $(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) $(INCL) -c -o $@ `test -f '$<' || echo '$(SRCDIR)/'`$<
.cpp.obj:
    $(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) $(INCL) -c -o $@ `if test -f '$<'; then  '$<'; else '$(SRCDIR)/$<'; fi`
.c.o:
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(INCL) -c -o $@ `test -f '$<' || echo '$(SRCDIR)/'`$<
.c.obj:
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(INCL) -c -o $@ `if test -f '$<'; then '$<'; else '$(SRCDIR)/$<'; fi`
```

This is the error message I am getting, although, as I said, the .o files are created in the directory, but it doesn't seem to find them to link them into my executable.

```
/bin/sh: 1: main.o: not found 
/bin/sh: 1: model.o: not found 
/bin/sh: 1: param.o: not found 
/bin/sh: 1: head.h: not found 
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status 
make: *** [project] Error 1
```

Note: this is the complete output I get:

```
g++ -O3 -fomit-frame-pointer -pipe -DNDEBUG -pedantic-errors -Wparentheses -Wreturn-type -Wcast-qual -Wall -Wpointer-arith -Wwrite-strings -Wconversion -I/installed/CoinAll/include/coin -I`/installed/CoinAll/include/coin`-I. -c -o main.o `test -f 'main.cpp' || echo '/root/projects/project'`main.cpp
/bin/sh: 1: /installed/CoinAll/include/coin: Permission denied
main-farmer.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
main-farmer.cpp:19:17: warning: variable ‘tiempo0’ set but not used [-Wunused-but-set-variable]
g++ -O3 -fomit-frame-pointer -pipe -DNDEBUG -pedantic-errors -Wparentheses -Wreturn-type -Wcast-qual -Wall -Wpointer-arith -Wwrite-strings -Wconversion -I/installed/CoinAll/include/coin -I`/installed/CoinAll/include/coin`-I. -c -o model.o `test -f 'model.cpp' || echo '/root/projects/project/'`model.cpp
/bin/sh: 1: /installed/CoinAll/include/coin: Permission denied
g++ -O3 -fomit-frame-pointer -pipe -DNDEBUG -pedantic-errors -Wparentheses -Wreturn-type -Wcast-qual -Wall -Wpointer-arith -Wwrite-strings -Wconversion -I/installed/CoinAll/include/coin -I`/installed/CoinAll/include/coin`-I. -c -o param.o `test -f 'param.cpp' || echo '/root//projects/project/'`param.cpp
/bin/sh: 1: /installed/CoinAll/include/coin: Permission denied
bla=;
for file in main.o model.o param.o head.h; do bla="$bla ` $file`"; done; \
    g++ -Wl,--rpath -Wl,/installed/CoinAll/lib -O3 -fomit-frame-pointer -pipe -DNDEBUG -pedantic-errors -Wparentheses -Wreturn-type -Wcast-qual -Wall -Wpointer-arith -Wwrite-strings -Wconversion -I/installed/CoinAll/include/coin -o farmer $bla -D. -L/installed/CoinAll/lib -lCbc -lCgl -lOsiClp -lOsi -lClp -lCoinUtils -lm `cat /installed/CoinAll/lib/cgl_addlibs.txt` `cat /installed/CoinAll/lib/clp_addlibs.txt` `cat /installed/CoinAll/lib/coinutils_addlibs.txt`  
/bin/sh: 1: main.o: not found
/bin/sh: 1: model.o: not found
/bin/sh: 1: param.o: not found
/bin/sh: 1: head.h: not found
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [project] Error 1
```

Answer (score 1):

In the for loop the following bit is incorrect.

```
` $$file`
```

It is incorrect since the `.o` files are not executables to be run for their output.

This makefile is quite terrible, you were correct about that.

Similar to the above issue.

This line is incorrect unless `$(COININCDIR)` is a command to run.

```
INCL=-I\`$(COININCDIR)\`$(ADDINCFLAGS)
```

This mistake is the cause of the `/bin/sh: 1: /installed/CoinAll/include/coin: Permission denied` errors.

Additionally, unless `$(ADDINCFLAGS)` is intended to be attached to the value of `$(COININCDIR)` (which it almost certainly isn't) a space is needed between the two variables.

Comment: How can I fix the ` $$file ` line?